# C in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ansi-c

We have to prepare a presentation in "Structured Programming" (**Ansi C**) about the usage of **C in Visual Studio**. I already found out how to make a C file and use the C++ compiler to run it, but there are still some questions left where i didn't found a awnser yet.

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); //seed for random number..
unsigned int ran = rand();

printf("Helloooo World");
printf("%u",ran);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

On Linux with vim it worked. But with Visual Studio I get the errors: 
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-25860939/Capture.jpg.html

1. Problem with my random seed.
2. Problem with the rand() function.

I think it is because of my included functions, and now my question is what functions Visual Studio owns for C, or what I have to change to make my program run in Visual Studio?

I would be really glad to read some answers. And i hope that i didn't was just to stupid to find the answers here.. :'D

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is not related to programming issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Your question seems to be about something you haven't shown us. For example, it talks about a "getchar(); call at the end". At the end of what? And it asks what libraries are included by some program. But what program?

Comment: `"standard" libraries: stdio.h, stdlib.h, time.h, string.h, unistd.h`...stop. How you came to conclusion that `.h` files are `libraries`, let alone be `standard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned int ran;//<--- Declare ran here.

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); //seed for random number..
    ran = rand(); ////<--- Use ran here (as before).

    printf("Helloooo World");
    printf("%u",ran);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 doesn't yet support C99. I mean it's only 12 years prior!!!

You have to declare your variables at the start of functions when compiling C.

I know! Shish!

Comment: Shishkebab.  VS2013 supports the syntax.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. I was aware 2012 didn't.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answer above.  You have also learned that:

- The Standard definition of the language is not interpretted the same
  by all people, including tool vendors.
- There are different versions of the Standard.
- And (if you've read the comments and done a bit of back-ground research) that header files included in the source used by the compiler are not the same thing as the library files that are used to build the executable by the linker.

You could end up with a great presentation.